# Search Twitter (using R and the TwitteR package) to get 200 results

Tags: r, twitter

How can I use the TwitterR package for R to get more than 100 search results?

Although I would prefer an example in R (since it currently uses R), I could just as easily use Java, so, an example that searches Twitter in Java to get 200 search results may suffice.

I don't know if this is even possible. I do not remember seeing a "page number" that you can specify when you search (The Google API supports that). I think that with Twitter you can specify the minimum Tweet ID, which allows you to get only newer tweets, but I don't expect that to work as desired in this case (unless the search results are some how ordered based on date / time rather than relevance to the search term).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitteR r package: How to get as many tweets as possible per account within API limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266528/twitter-r-package-how-to-get-as-many-tweets-as-possible-per-account-within-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting tweets this way.

`someTweets <- searchTwitter("#EroticBroadway", n=500)`

The `n` argument tells it how many tweets to cap it at. If there aren't that many tweets it won't return 500 though.

From the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/twitteR/docs/Rtweets):

> n The maximum number of tweets to return

There is also a [time limit on the twitter api search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.

The [**t** gem doesn't have that](https://github.com/sferik/t).

Answer (score 0):

You have to jump through more hoops, which has some (a lot of) disadvantages, but I've used [TAGS](https://tags.hawksey.info/) to collect hundreds of tweets (even thousands over the course of time...) and then read them into R as a CSV.